# Index of Dirac Operator

Tags: differential-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, then there exists a canonical Spin$^\mathbb{C}$ bundle on $X$ for any given complex line bundle $L$:
\begin{align*}
S^+=\bigoplus_i\Lambda^{2i}(X;L)\text{ and } S^-=\bigoplus_i\Lambda^{2i+1}(X;L)
\end{align*}
And once we put a metric $A$ on $L,$ we get a dirac operator
\begin{align*}
D:=\sqrt{2}(\bar\partial_A+\bar\partial^*_A):\Gamma(S^+)\rightarrow \Gamma(S^-)
\end{align*}

All the languages available mention that the index of this operator is
\begin{align*}
\int_X \text{ch}(L)Td(X)
\end{align*}
and this is equal to
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_i (-1)^i\text{ dim}_{\mathbb{C}}H^i(X,L)
\end{align*}
by Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch theorem. Now I have some doubts here, any clarification is most welcome.

So, what is Td$(X)$ here is it Td$(T^{1,0}(X))?,$ the Todd class of the holomorphic tangent bundle of $X$ or Todd class of the complexified tangent bundle of $X$? Secondly, this index is supposed to agree with the usual index I know about i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\text{dim$_\mathbb{R}$ Ker}(D)-\text{dim$_\mathbb{R}$ Coker}(D)
\end{align*}
Is that correct or I am supposed to count the dimension w.r.t. $\mathbb{C}$ everywhere?

Comment: (1) It is the holomorphic tangent bundle.  (2) that is correct.

Comment: @user10354138 see https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/ind-thm.pdf#page=105, last paragraph, doesn't it say it's actually counting everything w.r.t. $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @user10354138 also here https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/ind-thm.pdf#page=71 in theorem 2.1.38 doesn't it imply again that it has to be w.r.t. $\mathbb{C}$ as the e Euler characteristic of the complex $\sum\limits_i (-1)^i\text{ dim}_{\mathbb{C}}H^i(X,L)$ is counted w.r.t. $\mathbb{C}$?